# cut a file from a directory to another

Tags: directory, cut

Im tired to find an useful way to cut a file from a folder , I have search for this a lot of but ...

I have a code like this :

```
    File.Move(THIS DIRECTORY/MyFile.exe , (System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"MyFile.exe")));
    Console.WriteLine("successs");
```

it run without error but , I dont know that what is the directory of source file (it mean that ,i want to cut from directory of "Cutter.exe" file ) !

what can i do ?

thanks ;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this microsoft answer

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx
```

Thanks

Manoj